# What's the date displayed in a google search result?

Tags: google-search

My question is very simple, but I can't find any answer.

Here's a screenshot about what I talking about :

[image: Date in Google Search Result]

The date is "11 mai 2011".

---

### EDIT

I can say that this is not the last time that google has crawled the page because google cache has the version of this page for the feb. 7th:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:snL5u_JWSGsJ:www.scoop.it/t/journalisme-web+%22journalisme+web%22&cd=5&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr

Answer (score 1):

no answer, but a couple of item:

1. do not see a meta "Last-Modified" on page so cannot be that
2. do you have `robot.txt` that might be giving the last modified timestamp?

if you've found answer, please post!

Answer (score 0):

This is the date that Google crawled that page.

Answer (score 0):

It's the date that the [Google bot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlebot) last indexed/scanned that page.

Comment: It's very very strange because I can see that Google has a cached version for feb. 7th ...
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:snL5u_JWSGsJ:www.scoop.it/t/journalisme-web+%22journalisme+web%22&cd=5&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr